# How can i get an image from one div and put it in an image tag?

Tags: jquery

I need some help.
How can i get an image from one div and put it in an image tag with j query?
i mean some thing like this:

```
$('.myclass').click(function(){
    //put Image from div1 to img 1    
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code might server your purpose, looks like on click of some button you want to copy `src` of one `img` tag to other `img` tag in some `div`. Below code will help you.

HTML Code

```
<img id="oldimg" src="someurl" />
<div id="new">
    <img />
</div>
<button id="submit">
```

JQuery Code

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
    var srcv = $('#oldimg').attr('src');
    $('#new img').attr('src', srcv);

});
```

Comment: Thank you.i know it work.but its not the solution that i am looking for.actually i have a div and my image is in that div.and because i am using WordPress functions i don't have any src.